# How to get the difference of two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

So I have two arrays which looks like this when I do a var_dump :

```
array(4) { 
    ["DatabinFieldName_1"]=> string(7) "Heading" 
    ["DatabinFieldType_1"]=> string(13) "VARCHAR (255)" 
    ["DatabinFieldName_3"]=> string(11) "DateCreated" 
    ["DatabinFieldType_3"]=> string(8) "DATETIME" 
}

array(8) { 
    ["DatabinFieldName_1"]=> string(7) "Heading" 
    ["DatabinFieldType_1"]=> string(13) "VARCHAR (255)" 
    ["DatabinFieldName_2"]=> string(4) "Copy" 
    ["DatabinFieldType_2"]=> string(4) "TEXT" 
    ["DatabinFieldName_3"]=> string(11) "DateCreated" 
    ["DatabinFieldType_3"]=> string(8) "DATETIME" 
    ["DatabinFieldName_4"]=> string(8) "Comments" 
    ["DatabinFieldType_4"]=> string(4) "TEXT" 
}
```

I need to get the difference in a result. Which I have tried using this code.

```
// Get POST Array                               
$databinPostArray = $_POST;                             

// Get Databin Array
$databinObject =json_decode($nbase->getwhere("Databins","ID='".$databinID."' LIMIT 1;",$_SESSION["UserDB"]));
$databinArray= unserialize($databinObject[0]->DatabinArray);

var_dump($databinPostArray);
var_dump($databinArray);

$result = array_diff($databinPostArray, $databinArray);

print_r($result);
```

Problem is I keep getting `Array()` back which means its not finding any differences even though there is.

Comment: have you tried array_diff();

Comment: Problem is that you doing stuff wrong. `Array_diff` finds all elements of `array_1` which don't exists in `array_2`. According to your `var_dump` all elements of `$databinPostArray` exist in `$databinArray` so there's no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_diff()` returns the elements of the second array which are not in the first one.So the answer to your question is:

```
$result = array_diff($databinPostArray, $databinArray);
if (couunt($result) == 0) {
    $result = array_diff($databinArray, $databinPostArray);
}
```

This way, the difference will be returned, whether there is more keys in `$databinPostArray` or in `$databinArray`.

If what you want is only to check which elements are in `$databinArray`, but not in `$databinPostArray`, please do:

```
$result = array_diff($databinArray, $databinPostArray);
```

Comment: An empty array isn't falsey.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the arguments:

```
$result = array_diff($databinArray, $databinPostArray);
```

`array_diff` returns an array with everything in the first array that isn't in the second array.

If you want to get all the elements that are unique to either array, you can use:

```
$result = array_diff(array_unique(array_merge($databinArray, $databinPostArray)),
                     array_intersect($databinArray, $databinPostArray));
```